# I don't know why my bot doesn't answer after this code in python telegram

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, schedule, python-telegram-bot

```
import telebot
import requests
from telebot import types 
import time
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
import schedule

pole = False

TOKEN = '*******BOT TOKEN***********' 
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

def job():

    pole=True
    if pole == True:
        bot.send_message(chat_id,'poleadaaaaa')

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("21:24").do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

def listener(messages): 
        for m in messages: 
            if m.content_type == 'text': 
                cid = m.chat.id 
                print ("[" + str(cid) + "]: " + m.text) 

bot.set_update_listener(listener) 

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

    bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Hello you start the bot')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

If I put the following code the bot dont answer /start command and any text

```
def job():

        pole=True
        if pole == True:
            bot.send_message(chat_id,'poleadaaaaa')

    schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
    schedule.every().hour.do(job)
    schedule.every().day.at("21:24").do(job)

    while 1:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

I don't know why my bot doesn't answer if i put this code, because without this code it works perfect and answer at the moment in any case. I put the code before/after `def listener(messages):` and inside `@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])` but the bot doesn't respond.

Answer (score -1):

while 1:
    ....

Run this part in another thread.